# Unable to debug shaders using Nsight

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, nsight

I wrote an OpenGL Application with 2 shader programs used, both equipped with a vertex shader and a fragment shader
The shader programs just worked seemingly fine
But when I tried to debug these shader programs with Nsight 4.6 I found that I was unable to find any shaders in the "Shaders list" window.
By the way I was using a GPU for notebooks(NVIDIA GeForce GTX760M)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your OGL sample may still running on your Laptop's iGPU, but not NV's dGPU. Please try to add some codes to identify your renderer:

```
const GLubyte* glvendro = glGetString(GL_VENDOR);
const GLubyte* glrenderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
```

Make sure it's NV's GPU.

If it shows non NV's GPU, that means driver pick some other GPU, please try to force disable that GPU and make sure driver only find NV's GPU.

I know your meaning about 'switch the power management state to maxinum power, with GTX760M GPU forced on', but that may not work, you have to disable the non-NV GPU in hardware way, go into your BIOS and disable the iGPU.

If you can't find that option in BIOS, just find another monitor, connect it to NV's dGPU output [HDMI, or DP], force your sample run on that monitor will make it use dGPU.

Thanks
An

**Seems it's a duplicate of the thread in Nvidia's development forum https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/830717/nsight-visual-studio-edition/nsight-shader-list-is-empty/**

Comment: Thanks for your solution
I've tried to read the output of GL_VERSION, GL_VENDOR and GL_RENDERER, and here are the output strings:
OpenGL version: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 349.90
Current GPU Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Current Renderer: GeForce GTX 760M/PCIe/SSE2
So I'm 100% sure that my application was run by the dGPU

Comment: Currently I am able to use Nsight to view the OpenGL API calls but I still cannot debug shaders caz it's empty
Furthermore I am still unable to check the buffer storage using Nsight, for all the buffers displayed show that their memory location's 0x0000000000, which makes no sense.

As for disabling non-NV GPU using BIOS, tragically my laptop doesn't support this function to disable Optimus once and for all. However I do have an HDMI output port, so anyway are you sure that connecting another monitor to it will really work?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug shader code with current versions of NSight on Optimus enabled laptops.

Source: https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements